# Visual C, WinSock HTTP Req, and Non-Windows

Tags: c++, windows, http, visual-c++, winsock

I just have a simple question. I am a student and I am learning. I am not very proficient at C++, but I finally set up a working http reqest app in c++ using winsock and I just wanted to know that after compiling will the http request still be sent from other OSes that don't have WinSock?

Comment: What do you mean? Do you mean if a Linux PC sends a HTTP request to your app that it still works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WinSock, or at least the parts you probably will have been using for introductory networking stuff, is based off of, and largely compatible with, the BSD socket API, which is available on all current operating systems. If you don't have experience with cross-platform development it's unlikely that your code would compile the first time through on a Linux system, but the underlying techniques would be the same.

For cross-platform networking, you might want to consider something like Qt, which provides an API which will work mostly the same on all OSes without much per-platform stuff. Its networking API is also based off Berkeley sockets.

In general, though, there's just no way of checking that your code works cross-platform without testing it cross-platform. Grab a Linux distribution and try it out; note that some are specifically intended to work from your Windows disk without the need to repartition.

Answer (score 0):

If you use standardized BSD-based socket functions, then your code will typically work on multiple platforms `socket()`, `bind()`, `connect()`, `send()`, `recv()`, etc.  Caveats include:

1. error codes.  When a WinSock/BSD function fails on Windows, the error code is retreived using `WSAGetLastError()`, whereas other platforms use `errno` instead.  So you will have to wrap that portion if you are trying to write cross-platform code.
2. `get/setsockopt()` may implement different options on different platforms, not all options are standardized across all platforms.

If you use WinSock-specific functions, then your code will only work on Windows. `WSASocket()`, `WSAConnect/Ex()`, `WSASend/Ex()`, `WSARecv/Ex()`, etc.

All versions of Windows have WinSock.  Most platforms, including Windows, support a BSD-based socket API.

After you *compile* your code, it will only run on the specific platform it was compiled for.  You would have to compile the code separately for each platform you want to support.